# Ubuntu 18.04.3 Desktop Installation Problems

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, desktop-environments

I downloaded the iso image of Ubuntu 18.04.3 Desktop from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ and, following these instructions: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview I created a bootable USB.

I'm then trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 Desktop in a PC where it's already installed Ubuntu 18.04 Server Edition, which I want to replace,
but encountering these problems:

I'm following the steps:
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gKB6DrXdAdyJdPSIsrGWMuhnG2CZ_m24
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=14jZbOLgTAMgOfeWvF6XtlubKp5gGI1Bf

But at a certain step it goes back without the possibility to proceed further:
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pNuLScsaj9a_5avC3jmqtERSuwN6m3f_
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P50yodXE6qYIXlVWmocQcoR9JN1UaCWj

Update 01)

With a bootable iso usb with Ubuntu 18.04.02 Server Edition, I'm checking the disk for defects. And found one:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z8JNWfh547j5atuCwgWhX9IZu9-X1mit

can this single  defect cause the entire ubuntu 18.04.3 Desktop installation procedure to fail? And why the Ubuntu 18.04.4 till yesterday worked fine, even with that defect?

How to solve the problem?
Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Comment: In general, we care more about the exact commands you executed, and their actual results. "Following a procedure I got from the Internet" doesn't take into account your possible errors in following the procedure, and what the actual results are.

Comment: @waltinator if you are refering to the creation of bootable iso usb, I followed all the steps here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview and at the end a message "Now you can use your USB stick to install Ubuntu in other computer" appeared, which as far as I know, can be interpreted as "bootable usb creation ok"

Comment: Try selecting the option to "Try Ubuntu without installing" instead of doing an install. Than use the desktop icon to install ubuntu once you're system boots.

Comment: @Pachuca I already tried also in this way. Through the desktop icon I get stuck to the same point. With a bootable iso usb with Ubuntu 18.04.02 Server Edition, I'm checking the disk for defects. And found one. Please have a look at my update in the question above

Comment: Yes if a CD integrity check (one of your images; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
, where CD refers to any installation media used; be it cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive but usually thumb-drive these days) the install can fail; further the install shouldn't be trusted even if it worked. Thumb-drives don't do validation on data being written correctly & do fail on occasion even if it's only a few bits in a GB+ ISO; once data is there they're pretty good but the write is the hurdle.